# JSON response printing HTML instead of message

Tags: javascript, json, servlets

I'm trying to print a JSON response in my console. But here to my surprise the value that is getting printed in the console is the entire HTML page instead of the JSON response string.

Below is my code

```
<%@page import="org.bean.UserBean"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="myCssFile.css">
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.0.min.js"></script>

<title>Insert title here</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function enableSubmit() {
        document.getElementById("getCase").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("submitButton").disabled = false;
    }
    function enableGetCase() {
        document.getElementById("getCase").disabled = false;
        document.getElementById("submitButton").disabled = true;
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="header" id="header">
        <form id="form1">
            <input type="hidden" id="name" name="name1" value="index">
        </form>
        <span class="totalTime">Count is ${DAOCount}/${excelCount}</span> <span
            class="efficiency">${effeciency}</span>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" id="counter" value="${countValue}">
    <div class="bodytag">
        <form>
            <input type="Submit" value="Get Case" name="getCase" id="getCase"
                onclick="enableSubmit()" />

            <table>

                <tr>
                    <td>Case Number</td>
                    <td><input id="Text1" type="text" value="" /></td>

                    <td>Case Owner</td>
                    <td><input id="Text6" type="text" value="" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Source</td>
                    <td><input id="Text2" type="text" /></td>
                    <td>Status</td>
                    <td><input id="Text7" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="auto-style2">Issue</td>
                    <td class="auto-style2"><input id="Text3" value="" type="text" /></td>
                    <td class="auto-style2">Reason</td>
                    <td class="auto-style2"><input id="Text8" value="" type="text" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Date/Time Opened</td>
                    <td><input id="Text4" type="text" value="" /></td>
                    <td>Age(Days)</td>
                    <td><input id="Text10" type="text" value="" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Resolution</td>
                    <td><select id="Select1" name="D1">
                            <option></option>
                    </select></td>
                    <td>Final Status</td>
                    <td><select id="Select2" name="D2">
                            <option value="     "></option>
                    </select></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Start Time</td>
                    <td><input id="Text5" type="text" value="Start Time" /></td>
                    <td>End Time</td>
                    <td><input id="Text9" type="text" value="end Time" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <input type="button" value="Submit" name="submitButton"
                id="submitButton" disabled="disabled" onClick="enableGetCase()" />
        </form>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="indexJS.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

indexJS.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#form1").on('submit', function(e) {
        $.ajax({
            type : "get",
            url : "GetTheCounts",
            data : $(this).serialize(),
            success : function(msg) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(msg));
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    }).submit();
});
```

And my servlet is as below

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        GetTheCountsDAO getTheCountsDAO = new GetTheCountsDAO();
        try {
            response.setContentType("application/json");
            int excelCount = getTheCountsDAO.getTotalFromExcel();
            int DAOCount = getTheCountsDAO.getTotalFromDB();
            double getEffeciency = getTheCountsDAO.getEffeciency();
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            jsonObject.put("DAOCount", DAOCount);
            jsonObject.put("excelCount", excelCount);
            jsonObject.put("effeciency", getEffeciency);
            jsonObject.put("countValue", 1);
            String json = new Gson().toJson(jsonObject);
            response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
            System.out.println("Returned String is " + json);
            response.getWriter().write(json);
            request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(request, response);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Initially I thought that the issue might be with Servlet response, and when I did a `sysout` the value that is received is as expected. Below is the result.

Returned String is `{"DAOCount":43,"excelCount":882,"effeciency":81.94,"countValue":1}`

please let me know how can I get the same in my JS.

Thanks

Comment: I've never done server side Java, but if you are getting an HTML document that I'd be surprised if `request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(request, response);` was not the cause of it.

Comment: Hi @Quentin, You are life saver man. can you please add the above as an answer. I want to upvote it. This is what i was expecting. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(request, response);
> ```

After putting the JSON in the response, you perform a forward to your `index.jsp` which puts the Index HTML document in the response.